# TStringGrid show (bcd) in delphi live binding

Tags: delphi, firedac, tstringgrid

I connect TFDQuery with TStringGrid in live binding in delphi firemonkey apps.

I tried to use filter in TFDQuery based on Editbox for searching purpose, and it's work just fine.

but, whenever I clear the Editbox, one of my row in TStringGrid would show "(bcd)" as it's value like the pict below.

what am I doing wrong ? how can I fix it ?

[image]

Edit :

1. Im using mySql database with firedac tfdconnection + tfdquery
2. the datatype of the column is AnsiString & FmtBCS(32,0)
3. Im using live binding feature in delphi.
4. my filter code

   `with MainQuery do begin
   Filtered := False;
   OnFilterRecord := nil;
   Filter := FilterValue;
   Filtered := True;
   end;`
5. I Insert to the table with TFDConnection.execSQL

the "(BCD)" part always change on the selected Row as the pict below.

EDIT 2:
To Reproduce my error, you can :

1. add TStringGrid.
2. Add Editbox.
3. add tfdconnection
4. add tfdquery
5. use live binding from tfdquery to tstringgrid.
6. add query to tfdquery.sql.text that using SUM() in mysql. Example : `"select id, sum(stock) as total_stock from stocks"`
7. activate that tfdquery
8. add onkeyup event on editbox.
9. add this code :

`FilterValue:= 'garmines_id LIKE ''/' +Edit1.Text+'%'' ESCAPE ''/'' ';
    with FDQuery1 do  begin

    Filtered:= false;

    OnFilterRecord := nil;

    Filter := FilterValue;

    Filtered := True;

    end;`

10. run
11. try to type something on editbox to make sure filter works fine.
12. clear editbox, then the "(BCD)" is show on the selected row.

I reproduce this error. this is the SS :
[image]

Comment: There is insufficient information in your q for readers to be able to reproduce this problem.  Please ad to your q a) the type of DB your data is stored in, b) the data-type of the columns in the db table, c) the declared field types in your code and d) your code which constructs the filter.  Also, pls include some `InsertRecord` statements which insert the data shown into the db table.

Comment: @MartynA Already edited my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not include the InsertRecord statement I mentioned.  Anyway, I cannot reproduce your problem on a table with a single FmtBCD  field, so am reluctamt to spend any more time on it.  You need an MCVE - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, newbie. @MartynA please refer to second edit for clarify.

Comment: You still haven't provided an MCVE (note the Complete and Verifiable), your q is still missing details such as the DDL defintion of your table in the database, sample data and I don't see how any of the data rows you've shown would ever match your filter expression.  So, I'm voting to close this q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know what exactly causing this problem but I found the work around solution that avoid this problem appears.

you need to set `TStringGrid.selected` value to `-1` before refreshing the `TFDQuery`. so the code become :

```
FilterValue:= 'garmines_id LIKE ''/' +Edit1.Text+'%'' ESCAPE ''/'' ';

StringGrid1.selected := -1;

with FDQuery1 do  begin
  Filtered:= false;
  OnFilterRecord := nil;
  Filter := FilterValue;
  Filtered := True;
end;
```

I suspect that the cause of this problem is data type that come from mysql sum() method namely `FmtBCD(32)`

Answer (score 0):

Go to DataMapping Rules (firedac connection)
Mark ignore inherited rules
create 2 new rules

rule1: source: dtBCD / target datatype: dtDouble / all min: 0 / all max: 100
rule2: source: dtfmtbcd / target datatype: dtDouble / all min: 0 / all max: 100

click ok. now the fields will be dtDouble, and are compatible with tgrid